# z-index placing element below another one even though its higher

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

i have this drop down im adding into a wordpress site using visual composer, and im having trouble getting it to stack on top of a parallax section that is just below it. Even though ive over-riden the parallaxes div to z-index:-1 !important; and set my drop down to have a z-index of 99;

Heres a link to the page where im having the problem (scroll down to the WHERE TO BUY secion, its the second set of drop downs)

http://tinyurl.com/q6oom83

And heres the code im using for the custom styled drop downs

```
        function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
            this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;
                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                obj.opts.on('click',function(){                     
                    var ddid2 = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('.box').hide();
                    $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide()    
                    $('.'+ddid2).show();

                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
            var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd2') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set proper z-index to parent element of dropdown i.e. <div> element with id "buy" and also make it's overflow visible.

The dropdown was not visible because of overflow:hidden property of parent element.

CSS:

```
#buy
{
  z-index:99;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the page in your browser's dev tool.. the whole section is in an iframe - that is why the dropdown is cutt-off. I'm quite sure no element can overflow iframe...

And the second dropdown is not visible because the whole section (div with class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1434584724192 full-width-section") that is sibling to the paralax section has set overflow='hidden'

you have to add:

```
overflow:visible;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```

Comment: that is just the first set of drop down, look below right right on top of the parallax, that is not inside of an iframe (the reason im doing all this is to fix exactly that)